# Strict monotonicity implies FOSD under EU?

Tags: microeconomics, decision-theory

I think this result is very simple and very useful. However, I find no paper cover it.

Is it on some textbook like MWG?

Strict monotonicity means: $f(s)\succ g(s)$ for all $s$ implies $f\succ g$ and $f(s)\succsim g(s)$ for all $s$ implies $f\succsim g$.

Comment: First-order stochastic dominance is about lotteries over numbers ("money"). You seem to discuss acts in an Anscombe-Aumann-type framework. The monotonicity assumption you mention is always satisfied under (subjective) expected utility.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show that for the EU model, FOSD and monotonicity of the utility function implies preference dominance.

The reasoning is easier if we have a finite number of outcomes, say:
$$
x_1 > x_2 \ldots > x_n,
$$
Consider associated probabilities $p_1,\ldots, p_n$ and $q_1,\ldots, q_n$ over these outcomes.

Let $P_i = \sum_{j \le i} p_i$ be the probability that the outcome is larger or equal to $x_i$ and similarly, define $Q_i = \sum_{j \le i} q_i$.

We have that $p$ FOSD $q$ if $P_i \ge Q_i$ for all $i$ with at least one strict inequality. Note that $P_n = Q_n = 1$.

Let $u(x_1) > u(x_2) > \ldots > u(x_n)$. We would like to show that $\sum_{i = 1}^n p_i u(x_i) > \sum_{i = 1}^n q_i u(x_i)$.

Indeed:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n (p_i - q_i) u(x_i) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(\sum_{j \le i} p_j - \sum_{j \le i} q_j \right) u(x_i) - \sum_{i = 2}^n \left(\sum_{j < i} p_i - \sum_{j < i} q_i\right) u(x_i),\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n (P_i - Q_i) u(x_i) - \sum_{i = 2}^n (P_{i-1} - Q_{i-1}) u(x_i),\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n (P_i - Q_i) u(x_i) - \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} (P_j - Q_j)u(x_{j+1}),\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\underbrace{(P_i - Q_i)}_{\ge 0} \underbrace{(u(x_i) - u(x_{j+1}))}_{> 0} + \underbrace{(P_n - Q_n)}_{ = 0} u(x_n),\\
&> 0
\end{align*}
$$

Consider now the case of a continuous outcome $x \in [0,1]$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be two cdf, i.e. $P(x)$ is the probability that the outcome is smaller than or equal to $x$. We have that $P$ FOSD $Q$ if $P(x) \le Q(x)$ for all $x$ and $P(x) < Q(x)$ for at least one $x$. Assume that $P, Q$ are $C^1$ (and hence also continuous).

This implies that $P$ and $Q$ have have densities, say $p$ and $q$ and that there is an open neighbourhood of $[0,1]$ such that $P(x) < Q(x)$ for all $x$ in an open subset of $[0,1]$.

Finally, we assume that $u: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is also $C^1$. Monotonicity of $u$ then requires $u'(x) > 0$.

Note that:
$$
(u(x)P(x))' = u'(x) P(x) + u(x) p(x)
$$
So, we have the integration by parts identity.
$$
\underbrace{u(1)P(1) - u(0)P(0)}_{u(1)} = \int_0^1 u'(x) P(x) dx + \int_0^1 u(x) p(x) dx.
$$

We want to show that $\int_0^1 p(x) u(x) dx \ge \int_0^1 q(x) u(x) dx$.

Note:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 p(x) u(x) dx &= u(1) - \int_0^1 \underbrace{u'(x)}_{> 0} \underbrace{P(x)}_{\le Q(x)} dx,\\
&> u(1) - \int_0^1 u'(x) Q(x) dx,\\
&= \int_0^1 q(x) u(x) dx.
\end{align*}
$$
The strict inequality follows from the fact that $P(x) \le Q(x)$ with a strict inequality for all $x$ in an open (non-empty) subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Very detailed answer but is this what the OP was asking?